# Is this a valid redirect-rule return http 301?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am relaunching a website with over 10'000 pages, must adapt URL a tiny bit and need to be sure my redirect-rules are correct.

I simply need to add a "S" before the ID of that particular URL.

So can anyone tell me if this rule is correct and returning a http 301?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^http://www.slople.com/italia/venetien-veneto-friaul-julisch-venetien-venezien/romagnano-azzagoverona-grezzana/pendio-monte-sviola/S1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.slople.com/italia/venetien-veneto-friaul-julisch-venetien-venezien/romagnano-azzagoverona-grezzana/pendio-monte-sviola/1/ [R=301,L]
```

**Modified according to comment:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^http://www.slople.com/italia/venetien-veneto-friaul-julisch-venetien-venezien/romagnano-azzagoverona-grezzana/pendio-monte-sviola/1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.slople.com/italia/venetien-veneto-friaul-julisch-venetien-venezien/romagnano-azzagoverona-grezzana/pendio-monte-sviola/S1/ [R=301,L]
```

**More info**

To be more precise on my question, what I need is:

Redirect every URL with a numeric ID at the end (with or without trailing slash) *not* starting with "/activity"

Comment: Add or remove S? Your example removes the S.

Comment: whoopss... it should add!

Comment: @closetnoc so the 2nd example is correct?

Comment: Yes. It is possible to find a cleaner way of doing this to fit all scenarios, but it could gt a bit complicated. Are you changing all 10,000 pages? Perhaps a regular expression would help? Is the id always 1 digit or predictable in some way?? Such as always a number?

Comment: I admit that it looks like a big mess in htaccess :) and yes, the rules are: Only rewrite if the last part is a number (may or may not have trailing slash) and do not rewrite if the very first part after the TLD is "/activity"... Does it have negative performance impact on the Apache to have so many rules? I only need them for the first few days until searchengines have the new URLs...

Comment: It will take more than a few days for the search engines to re-index your pages. They work on their own schedule. ;-) It could be 6 months!! It would be slow to process 10k rules with each page view.

Comment: Got you... could you help me with the perfect redirect? I'm really stuck...

Comment: Just posted an answer!!

Comment: Just updated the answer- fixed regex to allow more than one digit number lengths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. There is a mod_dir http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html which provides for a trailing slash redirect. You might want to enable this to make your life a lot easier. It is the module `LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so` in your configuration- you may need to un-comment this out. This reduces half of the work.

From there, you can add the following code in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/activity.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1/S$2/ [R=301,L]
```

This should be a clean solution for you.

Comment: Thanks! This would not work with trailing slashes, right?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger It will! I told you about the mod_dir so that all requests will have a trailing slash. This then makes only this one rule necessary. Easy peasy!!

Comment: So I must enable mod_dir for this to work? Sorry I'm slow it seems ;)

Comment: Ooopppsss! I cut and pasted an IP address into the code by mistake. I updated the answer. Replace the www.example.com with your domain name.

Comment: If you want. I recommend it. It will take requests like www.example.com/something/something-else/2 and put a trailing slash so that it will be www.example.com/something/something-else/2/. The code I provided expects a trailing slash (which would be normal). I can modify the answer if you do not want to add mod_dir.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to activate it, but I can't figure out how to do it on MAMPpro / OSX... on the live server I suppose it will be easy...

Comment: seems it's already running locally and works like a charm... thank you very much!!

Comment: @RaphaelJeger Anytime!! I knew that a cleaner and simple redirect would do it for you.